# Attempts to center a button vertically for firefox results in an uneven menu in chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, rss, menubar

I've been trying to format the appearance of the RSS button in css, and for some reason there's a big difference between browsers. Chrome renders it perfectly, as if I don't need to mess with it at all. But on Firefox and IE9, it is uneven with the rest of the menu. So I added padding to even it out, and to elongate the hover colour to the bottom of the menu bar. That fixes the issue on Firefox, but it makes the menu uneven in the opposite way on Chrome. Suddenly the bar is too long for the other menu items.

```
.menunav a {
padding-right: 6px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 6px;
font-size: 100%;

}   
.menunav-rss:hover {
    background: #ff6600;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
```

This is coming from a wordpress site. I'm quite new to css or coding, so I'm not entirely sure how to amend this. Fixing one seems to make the other worse, and I'm not sure why only the rss button is uneven.

For reference, this is what the menubar appears without any padding on both Firefox and Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more information, I can easily give it.

Comment: if possible, provide a working example of the problem using jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Its due to browsers having different "preset" values. Think of it as each browser having their own stylesheet that gets applied before yours.

The only workaround really is to use a CSS reset. [Eric Mayers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is considered to be the 'goto' one, and covers pretty much everything you'd want it to.

Simply load the reset before your own styles, and then you should be able to adjust everything  to look more or less the same across all browsers.

It's a bit of a pain to have to do it, but you shouldnt really rely on the browser's built in default styling.

Comment: The reason I hate CSS resets is because I work with a lot of CMS systems. When the end user enters their blog post in the nice WYSIWYG editor, the CSS reset destroys their bullet lists (among other things). I'd much rather use a CSS normalizer that preserves some default styles for that reason. I think it's the web developer's job to know when a style for an element needs to be "reset", and it should only be reset for the purpose of styling the layout shell (nothing more).

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue multiple times. I've found that setting `vertical-align: top` makes it look the same in both FF and chrome (probably IE9 as well, although I haven't tested that), after which you can add `padding-top` to position the text within the anchor exactly where you want it.